# How to rename a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I thought the simple way to rename a column in SQL Server was

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
RENAME COLUMN OldColumnName TO NewColumnName;
```

This results in an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near 'RENAME'.

Did something change or am I doing something wrong?

How to rename a column in SQL Server?

Comment: Why not consult the official documentation?